# Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactory.GetVstoObject causes VBA memory leak?

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com, vsto

below is a minimum sample VSTO-Project that forces the Excel VBA-Environment to show an error "Not enough memory" and causes the VBA-Project to appear twice.

**Question: Is this a bug in the "GetVstoObject"-Method. How can I get around???**

**Steps:**

1. In Excel 2010: Create a new workbook and hit ALT + F11 to enter the VBA-Environment
2. In VBA.ThisWorkworkbook: Create an empty new Sub

   > Sub test()
   >
   > End Sub
3. Save the workbook as *Test.xlsm* and exit Excel.
4. Create a new *Excel 2010-Add-In* in Visual Studio
5. Replace all code in *ThisAddIn.cs* by the code below.
6. Start debugging Excel with F5
7. Start debugging *ExcelAddIn1* with F5
8. Open the saved workbook *Test.xlsm*.
9. ReOpen the saved workbook again (IMPORTANT: Must do it "externally" e.g. by using the Excel jumplist in the windows taskbar)

**Results:**

- The CTP is doubled
- If you hit ALT + F11 to open VBA, you will get an "No enough memory"-Error

Thanks for any explanation/solution!

Regards, 
Jörg

---

C# Minimum Add-In Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;

namespace ExcelAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.WorkbookActivate += new Excel.AppEvents_WorkbookActivateEventHandler(Application_WorkbookActivate);
        }

        void Application_WorkbookActivate(Excel.Workbook Wb)
        {
            //This is the important line:
            var activeVstoWorkbook = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Wb);
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```